# error: ld returned 1 exit status I Build failed: 2 errors

Tags: c++

This might be an obvious mistake of mine but for the life of me I can't figure out why I am getting this error. There is no indication of where the error's source is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int hrs;
        cout << "Enter hours worked (-1 to end):";
        cin >> hrs;
        if (hrs == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        double rate;
        cout << "Enter hourly rate of the employee ($00.00):";
        cin >> rate;
        double salary = 0.00;
        if (hrs <= 40)
        {
            salary = rate * hrs;
        }
        else
        {
            int otrate = rate * 1.5;
            salary = otrate * hrs;
        }
        cout << "Salary is $" << salary << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error message

```
||=== Build: Debug in AssignmentTwoQuestionOne (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| ld.exe
||  cannot open output file bin\Debug\AssignmentTwoQuestionOne.exe Permission denied| 
||  error: ld returned 1 exit status| 
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===| –
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: @NathanOliver ||=== Build: Debug in AssignmentTwoQuestionOne (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot open output file bin\Debug\AssignmentTwoQuestionOne.exe Permission denied|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://cpp.sh/2fbl6)

Comment: @NathanOliver I know it looks messy but I just copied contents to clipboard

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and rebuilding.  Also make sure you have permission to access the files in the location specified in the error.

Comment: Permission denied could also be that you are trying to compile while you still have the exe running

Comment: That as wierd sorry shouldn't have posted this. I copied the code to another project and it worked just fine. I am stumped

Comment: @CoryKramer You were right. Went into task manager and found a whole bunch of conhost.exe's open. Ended those and it worked fine.